# Pricing Calculator using Radio Buttons in Webflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, webflow

I am working on a pricing calculator and the code works but only for 2 sets of radio buttons. I am trying to add more than 2 radio buttons for my pricing calculator, but I can't seem to get it to work. I need to add up to 5 options, but cannot figure out how to embed the "else if" statement.

```
if($(this).prev().is('[name="Design"]')){
    sum = Number($(this).prev().attr('add-value')) 
       + (Number($('input[name="Seating"]:checked').attr('add-value')) || 0);
  }
  else{
    sum = Number($(this).prev().attr('add-value')) 
        + (Number($('input[name="Design"]:checked').attr('add-value')) || 0);
  }
```

```
if($(this).prev().is('[name="Design"]')){
    sum = Number($(this).prev().attr('add-value')) 
       + (Number($('input[name="Seating"]:checked').attr('add-value')) || 0);
  }
  else if{
    sum = Number($(this).prev().attr('add-value')) 
       + (Number($('input[name="Sound"]:checked').attr('add-value')) || 0);
  }
  else{
    sum = Number($(this).prev().attr('add-value')) 
       + (Number($('input[name="Design"]:checked').attr('add-value')) || 0);
  }
```

Comment: It's very difficult to understand, you have to show code of the corresponding HTML part, with the `<form>` element. It is not at all this way that we use radio buttons in javascript. You do not need to use some illegal attribute like `add-value`, radio buttons have already a value attribute.

Comment: I also have the feeling that you are confusing radio buttons with checkBoxes